# Powershell Select property with a variable as

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

The following script searches deletes statements in SSIS. These delete statements came from sql cache for some reason they came back with "]" missing. This missing brace is causing my select object to fail see error below. I cant remove braces before search else it will not find matches but leaving it on is causing issues with selection. Is there a way to ignore these braces during the select object. If the delete does not have any braces the script works like a charm.

```
$SearchStrings = Get-Content "C:\Users\someuser\Desktop\DataDumps_PS\Delete_input.txt"
$out_file = "C:\Users\someuser\Desktop\DataDumps_PS\Deletes$(get-date -f yyyyMMdd).txt"

$RootString = "E:\SSIS_packages\"
Foreach($SearchString in $SearchStrings){
Write-host $SearchString
                                        
Get-ChildItem $RootString -recurse | Select-String -pattern $SearchString | group path | 
Select-Object name,@{name="SearchString";expression={$SearchString.replace('[','').replace(']','')}}  | Export-Csv $out_file - 
append -NoTypeInformation -Force #select name, "$SearchString"
}
```

Error for deletes that have a missing brace.

```
Select-String : The string DELETE FROM [dbo].[APP_DMEVS_STG is not a valid regular 
expression: parsing "DELETE FROM [dbo].[APP_DMEVS_STG" - Unterminated [] set.
```

Comment: You could do a `-replace` inside of your `expression={....}`

Comment: I was thinking along those lines but I would need to replace 2 characters "[" and "]" can i do that with one replace?

Comment: @LeoTorres You can do that with two replaces chained together `-replace '[','' -replace ']',''`

Comment: I have tried these 2 expressions and still get the same error

Comment: #$SearchString -replace '[','\[' -replace ']','\]'
#$SearchString.replace('[','').replace(']','')

Comment: and $SearchString -replace '[','' -replace ']',''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it's failing on interpreting it as a regular expression.  Try replacing this

```
Select-String -pattern $SearchString
```

with this

```
Select-String -SimpleMatch "$SearchString"
```

Comment: I replaced it with. Get-ChildItem $RootString -recurse | Select-String -pattern $SearchString | group path | Select-Object name,@{name="SearchString";expression={$($SearchString.replace('[','')).replace(']','')}}  | Export-Csv $out_file -append -NoTypeInformation -Force #select name, "$SearchString"
still same error.

Comment: The last change -simplematch worked no errors thank you!